Is a question about the balance of an entirely new class answerable on this site?
I found a homebrew Summoner class on DMsGuild that looks balanced, as well as fun to play. However, I'm not sure whether entire are appropriate for this site, although I've seen several different examples of this. Is it appropriate to ask questions about the balance of entire homebrew classes on this site?

To get the most out of it, focus your question on the subclass and level range you’re actually going to play.
I’ve seen huge questions like this fall flat numerous times. Reviewing an entire class, with multiple subclasses, from levels 1 to 20, is a tremendous undertaking and often solicits broad, overview-type answers rather than detailed analysis. If you really want useful, in-depth analysis, focusing the question on the character choices you actually intend to play and the level range your game will include may go a long way to encouraging others to actually look a bit deeper into your question.
Think about it: do you really need an analysis of the 16th level features of subclasses B and C when you’re only going to be taking subclass A to 8th level? Of course not; just focus the question on the features of the class you’re actually going to use, because those are the features that will impact your game.
